# How can I make a reference at the end of a page that will describe a person that I mentioned in my text?

Tags: cross-referencing, citing, footnotes

I am doing my thesis in LaTeX, and I mentioned the name of a scientist.

I'd like to create a reference at the end of the page, describing who that person is.  For instance: *French physicist, Head of Astrophysics department at Y university.*

I don't know how to do it and consequently what is the correct way to structure this.

Comment: Probably you could use a footnote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a **footnote** to reference the word/name.

```
\documentclass{article}


\begin{document}

Didier Deschamps\footnote{French physicist, Head of Astrophysics department at Y university.}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a piece of work, which you can cite it is probably best not to use citations and/or references. I would go for `\footnote{<description>}`, this will insert a ''*'' where the `\footnote{}` appears and put your description at the bottom of the page